# How can I close the figure window in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [2,4,6,8]


def func():
    fig,ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.pause(1)
    plt.plot(l1,l2)
    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(1)
    input("press any key to continue...")
    plt.close()
    plt.pause(1)

while True:
    func()
    plt.pause(1)
```

I want to open and close the figure window every time in the loop. I don't want to see the window when it closes. I thought `plt.close()` could work this way, but it doesn't in the while True loop. The window doesn't close even when I click the x button in the upper left. I have no idea how to solve this problem. Please help me out! ToT

Comment: This works as I would expect.   You keep creating a new figure, so there is always a figure until you kill the process

Comment: I thought so, too. So I changed plt.pause(1) in the last line of func as plt.pause(10). But I still saw the figure though it is closed.